# Getting "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object" when attempting to call the cancel function in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-button, custom-field

I'm making a system for our custom packages.
When attempting to assign the packages from a visualforce page to the Opportunity I end up getting this the error.
This error only happens when clicking the Add Packages button. Otherwise the page appears to be working fine.

Line 91 is the line with:

```
PageReference cancel = controller.cancel();
```

**Visualforce Error:**

```
public class MetadataPackageEditor{
//------------------------------ Extension Code-----------------
private final Package__c pPackage;

private final Opportunity_Package__c oppPackage;

private final Opportunity opp;    
    // The extension constructor initializes the private member
    // variable acct by using the getRecord method from the standard
    // controller.


    public MetadataPackageEditor(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        sObjectType oType = stdController.getRecord().getsObjectType();

        if (oType == Package__c.sObjectType){
            this.pPackage = (Package__c)stdController.getRecord();
        }

        else if (oType == Opportunity_Package__c.sObjectType) {
            this.oppPackage = (Opportunity_Package__c)stdController.getRecord();
        }

        else if (oType == Opportunity.sObjectType)
        {
            this.opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        }
    }
// Reference for page returns
Private ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;

public MetadataPackageEditor(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdController) {

        sObjectType oType = stdController.getRecord().getsObjectType();

        this.controller = stdController;

        if (oType == Package__c.sObjectType){
            this.pPackage = (Package__c)stdController.getRecord();
        }

        else if (oType == Opportunity_Package__c.sObjectType) {
            this.oppPackage = (Opportunity_Package__c)stdController.getRecord();
        }

        else if (oType == Opportunity.sObjectType)
        {
            this.opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        }
    }    
//-------------------------------------End of Extension code------------------


public List<pPackage> packageList {get;set;}

public List<pPackage> getPackages() {
    if(packageList == null) {
        packageList = new List<pPackage>();
        for(Package__c p: [SELECT Id, Name, PPU_Discount__c, Expiration_Date__c, Products__c FROM Package__c]) {
            packageList.add(new pPackage(p));
        }
    }
    return packageList;
}

public List<Package__c> selectedPackages {get;set;}

public PageReference processSelectedPackages() {
    selectedPackages = new List<Package__c>();

    for(pPackage pPack: getPackages()) {
        if(pPack.selected == true){
            selectedPackages.add(pPack.pack);
        }
    }
    packageList=null;
    return null;
}

//Add all of the selected packages and return to the previous page
public String oppId {get;set;}

public PageReference processAndAddSelected(){
if(controller != null){
if(oppId != null){
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(id=oppId);
    processSelectedPackages();
if(selectedPackages != null && selectedPackages.size()>0){    
    for(Package__c pack: selectedPackages){
        Opportunity_Package__c oppPack = new Opportunity_Package__c();
        oppPack.Name = pack.Name;
        oppPack.Opp_Package_Rel__c = opp.Id;
        oppPack.Package_Opp_Rel__c = pack.Id;
        insert oppPack;
    }
   }

   else{
       throw new MetadataServiceExamplesException('Request failed due to selectedPackages being NULL.');
   }

    return controller.cancel();
    }
    else{
        throw new MetadataServiceExamplesException('Request failed due to oppId being NULL.');
        }
        }
    else{
        throw new MetadataServiceExamplesException('Request failed due to Controller being NULL.');
    }
}

public void pullStandardProducts () {

  MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();     
        MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
        customField.fullName = 'Package__c.Products__c';
        customField.label = 'Products';
        customField.type_x = 'MultiselectPicklist';
        customField.visibleLines = 7;
        metadataservice.Picklist pt = new metadataservice.Picklist();
        pt.sorted= false;


    Id stdPricebook = [
        SELECT ID
        FROM Pricebook2
        WHERE IsStandard = true].Id;

    List<PricebookEntry> products = [
        SELECT Name
        FROM PricebookEntry
        WHERE Pricebook2Id = :stdPricebook];

    List<MetadataService.PicklistValue> valuesToAdd = new List<MetadataService.PicklistValue>();

    for (Integer j = 0; j < products.size(); j++){
        MetadataService.PicklistValue tempValue = new MetadataService.PicklistValue();
        tempValue.fullName = products.get(j).Name;
        tempValue.default_x = false;
        valuesToAdd.add(tempValue);
    }

    pt.picklistValues = new List<MetadataService.PicklistValue>();

    pt.picklistValues.addAll(valuesToAdd);

        customField.picklist = pt ;
        List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =      
            service.updateMetadata(
                new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
        handleSaveResults(results[0]);

}


public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService()
    { 
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        return service;     
    }

public static void handleSaveResults(MetadataService.SaveResult saveResult)
    {
        // Nothing to see?
        if(saveResult==null || saveResult.success)
            return;
        // Construct error message and throw an exception
        if(saveResult.errors!=null) 
        {
            List<String> messages = new List<String>();
            messages.add(
                (saveResult.errors.size()==1 ? 'Error ' : 'Errors ') + 
                    'occured processing component ' + saveResult.fullName + '.');
            for(MetadataService.Error error : saveResult.errors)
                messages.add(
                    error.message + ' (' + error.statusCode + ').' + 
                    ( error.fields!=null && error.fields.size()>0 ? 
                        ' Fields ' + String.join(error.fields, ',') + '.' : '' ) );
            if(messages.size()>0)
                throw new MetadataServiceExamplesException(String.join(messages, ' '));
        }
        if(!saveResult.success)
            throw new MetadataServiceExamplesException('Request failed with no specified error.');
    }
    }
```

**Visualforce:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity_Package__c" extensions="MetadataPackageEditor" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
  <apex:form >

      <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity_Package__c.Opp_Package_Rel__c}"/>

      <apex:pageBlock title="Select Package(s)">
      <apex:pageMessages />

          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!packages}" var="o" id="table">
              <apex:column title="Select" headerValue="Select">
                  <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!o.selected}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column value="{!o.pack.Name}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!o.pack.Products__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!o.pack.PPU_Discount__c}" headerValue="Price per Unit Discount"/>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <apex:commandButton value="Add Packages" action="{!processAndAddSelected}">
          <apex:param name="oppIdParam" value="{!Opportunity_Package__c.Opp_Package_Rel__c}" assignTo="{!oppId}"/>
      </apex:commandButton>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
      </apex:pageBlock>



  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The error is saying that you are trying to use a variable that is null. The error is happening in `MetadataPackageEditor.processAndAddSelected` on line 96. If you can show which line is 96 then people will be able to provide more help.

Comment: Okay, made an edit to the main post. It is the like with PageReference cancel on it

Comment: That means that `controller` is null for some reason.

Comment: Any idea why? It very clearly gets an assignment. And it's saying it's de-referencing a null object, not that it's a null value assignment issue

Comment: `controller` is null. SalesForce just has a strange way of reporting the error.  There was a question on here which explained why its phrased like that but I cant find it. The controller is set in the constructor otherwise you would of got an NPE on `stdController.getRecord()`

Comment: Okay I did a check and controller is null. The question still remains why? It's being assigned properly, at least I think so.

Comment: Can you post all your code? Maybe something else is happening that is affecting the controller variable

Comment: I have added all my code to the post. I also simultaneously realized my issue. I have this within a set constructor, and not a standard constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the `controller` variable is null. You have two constructors and are only setting `controller` in one of them.

This is the constructor that is getting called:

```
public MetadataPackageEditor(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
```

Where as you only set the `controller` variable in the constructor below

```
public MetadataPackageEditor(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdController)
```

Comment: You posted before I could, thank you though this was the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

//Add null check around this for loop

```
public PageReference processAndAddSelected(){
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(id=oppId);
    processSelectedPackages();
if(selectedPackages != null && selectedPackages.size()>0){
    for(Package__c pack: selectedPackages){
        Opportunity_Package__c oppPack = new Opportunity_Package__c();
        oppPack.Name = pack.Name;
        oppPack.Opp_Package_Rel__c = opp.Id;
        oppPack.Package_Opp_Rel__c = pack.Id;
        insert oppPack;
    }
}
    PageReference cancel = controller.cancel();
    return cancel;
}
```

Comment: Added this, and even added an else statement to throw an exception if it's null. Yet I still get the same error.

Comment: What part of code is falling under line 91 before you make change.

Comment: line 91:       PageReference cancel = controller.cancel();

Comment: there might issue with the opportunity, you are just passing as opp.id, Try passing the OppId directly instead of writing this line Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(id=oppId); beacuse you are getting that value directly from page and you no need to do the above line. do null checkon  OppId too.

Comment: I can't as it needs to be passed as a param from the page, so it can dynamically know which opportunity it is adding it to.

Comment: comment that  line and change the return type as follows return Controller.cancel();

Comment: I did a check to see if oppId was null, and it is not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21643/discussion-between-suri-and-cody-beaner).